# problema con import com.google.android.gms

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Quiero usar la api de google maps pero no puedo importar lo siguiente, ya que marca como desconocido todo lo que quiero importar:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

Busque informacion y es por que debo tener instalado **Google Play Services** pero ya lo tengo descargado, que puedo hacer?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente agrega la dependencia en tu build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    ...

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    }
```

Al tener configurada la dependencia la descargara.

En la documentación puedes ver como agregarla o agregar una Google Play services API individual diferente de acuerdo a tus requerimientos.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup